# Cannot push content of folders to remote repo in Git

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, git-push

I encounter following problem. I am working on a project in Java using Eclipse IDE. Our team have remote git repository on Bitbucket. I decided to import our current project to my local computer. As we do not store eclipse project files and only Java source files I have taken following steps to make a new project with our current java files:

1. Imported project from git repository so:

   a) `File > Import... > Git > Projects from Git > clone URI`

   b) In URI text field I copied the URI that was provided as clone http address

   c) checked all available branches to import and then created a new empty project (let's name it '***myProj***').
2. Right clicked on newly created project src folder and selected *Import...* option. In the Import dialog I have chosen `General > File System` and then navigated to my imported git folder and selected all the folder and subfolders available and clicked Finish. Now my *src* folder was filled with the files from repository and it was fine.
3. I created new packages and added some new java classes to them and I wanted to commit and push these changes to my remote repository. In order to do that I did the following in my project:

   a) `myProj > Team > Share project...` and chose my repository

   b) now as I can share my project I did: `myProj > Team > Commit...` then wrote the commit message, checked all the files to commit and then clicked `Commit and push` button and did all further steps.

Then I navigated to the bitbucket website to check if all went correctly but found out that only the folder with the project name was pushed and it was empty. Now I'm confused what is the reason of this behaviour because in Eclipse in Git Repositories window I have this:

[image]

However in my bitbucket repository I have no files in my folder. Anyone knows what is the reason and how to fix it so that I can push all files to repository?

Comment: Did you add the changed files before commiting and pushing?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it to be a bug in Egit (eclipse's git implementation). Do right click on root folder and select **Team / Commit** and check the files that now eclipse allows you to commit (so probably it will allow you to add all lacked content).

Comment: nm_______________________________________________

Comment: In available files to commit I have only *lebara-all/src* and after getting mouse over this I have a tooltip: *Mod. not staged*. When I try to commit this I am not able as there are no changes detected. Amending commit is not working as well.

Comment: Do your new files appear in eclipse with the "?" symbol? Do they have git history when you select them and do right click and team/ show in history? have  you tried to checkout your project again from bitbucket (to another folder) and check if it's really empty?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unusual way of working with EGit. I would expect you clone the repo and then import the project by right clicking on `Working Directory` in `Git Repositories` view and selecting `Import projects...`. If you do not store Eclipse config in git, you would have to use import as general project and then 'configure' it (in case of Java most likely by manually editing `.project` and creating `.classpath` files).

If you are content with what you already have. Then there is a way to get EGit working with this. I suspect that your new project is not managed by Git, since you have just copied (and possibly linked) the sources to git working directory.
In order to make EGit aware of it, delete the project from workspace but *without deleting contents*. Then right click the folder in `Git Repositories` select `import projects...` and choose `import existing Eclipse projects`. This will restore the project with all of its config and will let you use `Git Staging` view to author the commit.